# Dandelion datatables exporting to Excel - missing export links

Tags: spring, datatables, apache-poi, thymeleaf, dandelion

I've asked question on Dandelion forum but I did not recieve any answer so I am trying here. AFAIK the creator of Dandelion answers here as well so maybe I will be lucky this time.

My stack is Spring 4, Thymeleaf and Dandelion Datatables 0.10.1. What I am trying to achieve is simple exporting. I've started with [filter based exports](http://dandelion.github.io/datatables/features/export/filter-based-exports.html) but as my tables are populated by AJAX call it did not work.

So I've switched to [controller based export](http://dandelion.github.io/datatables/features/export/controller-based-exports.html) - I've added all the code to my Spring app but the problem still remains. **There is no export link generated in a view layer!** My Thymeleaf code looks like this.

```
<table id="appConfig" class="table-striped table-bordered dataTable" dt:export="xlsx,pdf,csv,xls" dt:table="true" dt:url="URL_WHERE_DATAATBLES_CONTROLLER_WORKS"
       dt:pageable="true" dt:paginationtype="full_numbers" dt:serverside="true" dt:processing="false" dt:dom="frtlpi">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th dt:property="key"><span>Parameter Key</span></th>
        <th dt:property="value"><span>Parameter Value</span></th>
        <th dt:sortable="false" dt:renderFunction="renderEditButton"></th>
        <th dt:sortable="false" dt:renderFunction="renderDeleteButton">/th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

My datatable works fine - it retrieves data from the server (with AJAX call) but there is no export link anywhere. How it is supposed to work or behave then? Am I doing something wrong?

PS. Why there is no 'dandelion' tag? I think it will be good for dandelion-related questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As soon as you activate export, Dandelion-Datatables makes available a new control element accessible through the **E** parameter and automatically updates the [dom](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) parameter to include this new control.

Since you override with the **dt:dom** parameter, you need to specify the new control, for example with: `dt:dom="Efrtlpi`

Disclaimer, as required by SO rules: I'm an author of the library.

> Why there is no 'dandelion' tag? I think it will be good for dandelion-related questions.

Because I have not enough reputation yet but I'd love to have one :-)

Comment: [tag:dandelion] has been created, you'll probably want to suggest edits to existing questions to re-tag them to use it. A tag wiki would be good too, if you can write one that isn't too much self-promotion!